# I can't repaint my form in Delphi

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I'm creating a Delphi program and i have this code in my program:

```
begin
  if edit1.Text='salam' then
  begin
    for i := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      progressbar1.Value := progressbar1.Value+1;
      sleep(100);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I wanna have the progressbar moving smoothly. But this code isn't like that.
What should i do? I wanna repaint the form after sleep.

Comment: You're doing `sleep` in the GUI thread (where everything else is done) and keeping the UI from repainting. You have to do it in another thread, or use a `TIdAntiFreeze` component on your form.

Comment: Surely your real code isn't doing a sleep. What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I think you forgot the `begin` after the do, and the `end` after the sleep.  Surely you didn't want to loop over only the line  that sets progressbar1.value?

Comment: @WarrenP Read the comments to Cesar's answer.

Comment: I wonder if Sleep(x) is even WORSE idea on iOS. Probably it is.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this...

```
begin
  if edit1.Text='salam' then
  begin
    progressbar1.Step:=1;
    for i := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      progressbar1.StepIt;
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      Sleep(100);
    end
  end;
end;
```

Windows needs to process the messages to repaint and to know your app isn't frezzed, Application.ProcessMessages does that magic.

Comment: I haven't step in my progressbar. I'm creating an iOS HD application. Is it important?

Comment: I haven't developed anything for iOS, so i'm not sure that Application.ProcessMessages exists, but if it doesn't there must be an equivalent.

Comment: as Cesar says, the important part is Application.ProcessMessages.  StepIt is just something new for you.  your question doesn't mention iOS HD & i don't know whether they work there but i suspect they will.

Comment: This is still wrong in many ways. Your code is fine for a silly demo, but don't ever write code like this in production. You should almost never sleep in the main thread, and certainly never sleep inside a loop. Adding Application.ProcessMessages cures the obvious problem of a frozen main window message loop, but it can cause other interesting side effects in large production applications.

Comment: @WarrenP is right, but since it's just a simple progress bar, there is no need to write more complicated code to accomplish this.

Comment: @Cesar I'm not sure I follow your logic. I see now reason why code as simple as this could not have problems induced by a call to `ProcessMessages`. That said, I have simply no idea what `ProcessMessages` means on iOS/FMX.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well do you know what ProcessMessages does in Windows? it simply handles the queue of system messages for your application. If you are going to do something simple that is gonna take some time to respond and you don't want to do it in a different thread you can use ProcessMessages instead.

Comment: that re-entrancy could allow all sorts of things to happen. For example the progress bar could be destroyed.